# from green to red color depend on percentage

Tags: javascript

I have a poll system and I want answers for this poll to be colored.
For example: If it's 10% it would be red, if 40% it would be yellow and if 80% it would be green, so I want my javascript code to use the rgb colors to make a color according to the given percentage.

```
function hexFromRGB(r, g, b) {
    var hex = [
        r.toString( 16 ),
        g.toString( 16 ),
        b.toString( 16 )
    ];
    $.each( hex, function( nr, val ) {
        if ( val.length === 1 ) {
            hex[ nr ] = "0" + val;
        }
    });
    return hex.join( "" ).toUpperCase();
}
```

Now I want hex from percent.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/percent-to-hex

Answer (score 123, accepted):

This may be more than you need, but this lets you set up any arbitrary color map:

```
var percentColors = [
    { pct: 0.0, color: { r: 0xff, g: 0x00, b: 0 } },
    { pct: 0.5, color: { r: 0xff, g: 0xff, b: 0 } },
    { pct: 1.0, color: { r: 0x00, g: 0xff, b: 0 } } ];

var getColorForPercentage = function(pct) {
    for (var i = 1; i < percentColors.length - 1; i++) {
        if (pct < percentColors[i].pct) {
            break;
        }
    }
    var lower = percentColors[i - 1];
    var upper = percentColors[i];
    var range = upper.pct - lower.pct;
    var rangePct = (pct - lower.pct) / range;
    var pctLower = 1 - rangePct;
    var pctUpper = rangePct;
    var color = {
        r: Math.floor(lower.color.r * pctLower + upper.color.r * pctUpper),
        g: Math.floor(lower.color.g * pctLower + upper.color.g * pctUpper),
        b: Math.floor(lower.color.b * pctLower + upper.color.b * pctUpper)
    };
    return 'rgb(' + [color.r, color.g, color.b].join(',') + ')';
    // or output as hex if preferred
};
```

Comment: Wow, thanks Mister @Jacob ^-^ 
[https://jsfiddle.net/JeancarloFontalvo/1sco9Lpe/3/](https://jsfiddle.net/JeancarloFontalvo/1sco9Lpe/3/)

Comment: Thanks so much for this solution. What need's to be done to make the green a bit darker like a dark-green? The solution above is hard to read on the website I'm working on!

Comment: @Chris: you'd modify that last color `{ pct: 1.0, color: { r: 0x00, g: 0xff, b: 0 } }` to a darker RGB color. For example, changing `g` to `0x7f` will make it half as bright. I'd suggest playing around with a color picker to choose which endpoints you want, and this should blend smoothly among them.

Answer (score 164):

A simple scheme using HSL along with fiddle:

```
function getColor(value){
    //value from 0 to 1
    var hue=((1-value)*120).toString(10);
    return ["hsl(",hue,",100%,50%)"].join("");
}
```

tweak saturation and luminosity as needed.  and a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jongobar/sNKWK/)**.

```js
function getColor(value) {
  //value from 0 to 1
  var hue = ((1 - value) * 120).toString(10);
  return ["hsl(", hue, ",100%,50%)"].join("");
}
var len = 20;
for (var i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
  var value = i / len;
  var d = document.createElement('div');
  d.textContent = "value=" + value;
  d.style.backgroundColor = getColor(value);
  document.body.appendChild(d);
}
```

Comment: So, it's a black box. Any explanation?

Comment: From red to green. var hue=(value*120).toString(10);

Comment: How could you adapt this to include a min and max value?  For instance, `getColor(12,0,100)` (`getColor(value, min, max)`)?

Comment: Scratch that, doesn't work 100%: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40110721/generate-gradient-step-based-on-dynamic-value-including-decimals

Comment: @SaeedNeamati It sets the hue between 0 and 120 (representing red through green) based on the value you pass (0 through 1). It converts the hue to a string ("0" through "120"), then returns a string coding the color in hsl format (hue, saturation, lightness), with saturation set to 100% and lightness set to 50%.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, very clean. Thanks!

Comment: worth mentioning that the color is `red > 0.5 > green`, meaning if calculating progress with `width` (1 done, 0 nothing), you need to subtract 1 from the width value given: `getColor( 1 - width ) {...}` to achieve green at 100% progress and red at 0%. awesome function thank you!

Comment: Thanks, or in ES6 `const getColor = v => hsl(${((1 - v) * 120)},100%,50%);` http://jsfiddle.net/pcmsdjL8/

Comment: I love stackoverflow!

Comment: Here is npm package based on your code: https://www.npmjs.com/package/percent-to-hex

Answer (score 41):

You can do this in a few lines of code (not including comments) without the need for any color maps.

```
function hsl_col_perc(percent, start, end) {
  var a = percent / 100,
      b = (end - start) * a,
      c = b + start;

  // Return a CSS HSL string
  return 'hsl('+c+', 100%, 50%)';
}
//Change the start and end values to reflect the hue map
//Refernece : http://www.ncl.ucar.edu/Applications/Images/colormap_6_3_lg.png

/*
Quick ref:
    0 – red
    60 – yellow
    120 – green
    180 – turquoise
    240 – blue
    300 – pink
    360 – red
*/
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/x363g1yc/634/

No need for color maps (Unless it is a non-linear color change, which was not asked)

Warning:
 This is not compatible with IE8 or below. (Thanks Bernhard Fürst)

```js
// Just used as a shortcut for below, completely optional
const red = 0,
  yellow = 60,
  green = 120,
  turquoise = 180,
  blue = 240,
  pink = 300;

function hsl_col_perc(percent, start, end) {
  var a = percent / 100,
    b = (end - start) * a,
    c = b + start;

  // Return a CSS HSL string
  return 'hsl(' + c + ', 100%, 50%)';
}

// Simple little animation
var percent = 0,
  progressDiv = document.getElementById('progress'),
  textDiv = document.getElementById('progress-text'),
  progressContainerDiv = document.getElementById('progress-container')

function step(timestamp) {
  percent = (percent < 100) ? percent + 0.5 : 0;

  // Play with me!
  let colour = hsl_col_perc(percent, red, green); //Red -> Green
  progressDiv.style.backgroundColor = colour;
  progressContainerDiv.style.borderColor = colour;
  progressDiv.style.width = percent + '%';
  textDiv.innerHTML = Math.floor(percent);
  window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
```

```css
#progress {
  width: 0%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-wrap: none;
  height: 50px;
}

#progress-container {
  border: solid 2px black;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="progress-text"></h1>
<div id="progress-container">
  <div id="progress"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Using the HSL color model is cool but it does not work in Internet Explorer 8, unfortunately.

Comment: This is true, I'll amend my answer

Comment: Can you explain `start` and `end` in this?

Comment: Start is the starting color, end is the ending color. So for example. hsl_col_perc(100,0,120) will be 100% green (refer to color table above). You could do hsl_col_perc(100,0,180) will be 100% turquoise

Comment: No, `end` is the difference between start and end color in the code above. `hsl_col_perc(100, 60, 120)` will result in turquoise instead of green. You need to change the second line to `b = (end-start)*a`, or just make it a one-liner since that would be easier to read.

Comment: I've updated the example to make it much simpler to grasp how it might look

Comment: Thanks for leaving in the quick HSL color ref!

Answer (score 14):

This method works well in this case (percent from 0 to 100):

```
function getGreenToRed(percent){
            r = percent<50 ? 255 : Math.floor(255-(percent*2-100)*255/100);
            g = percent>50 ? 255 : Math.floor((percent*2)*255/100);
            return 'rgb('+r+','+g+',0)';
        }
```

Answer (score 14):

I know this is originally an old javascript question, but I got here searching for *CSS only solution*, so maybe it will help others equally:
It's actually quite simple:

Use the percentage as a HSL color value!
Red to Green spans H from `0` to `128`.(so you can pump the percentage up by `1.2` if you want). Example:

```
background-color:hsl(perc,100%,50%);
```

Where perc is just the number, without the `%` sign.

Answer (score 8):

I've modified zmc's answer to give a gradient from green (0%) to red(100%).

```
const getGreenToRed = (percent) => {
  const r = (255 * percent) / 100;
  const g = 255 - (255 * percent) / 100;
  return 'rgb(' + r + ',' + g + ',0)';
};
```

**Edit:**

Just revisiting this years later... here is a more flexible implementation for any colors.

```js
const interpolateBetweenColors = (
  fromColor,
  toColor,
  percent
) => {
  const delta = percent / 100;
  const r = Math.round(toColor.r + (fromColor.r - toColor.r) * delta);
  const g = Math.round(toColor.g + (fromColor.g - toColor.g) * delta);
  const b = Math.round(toColor.b + (fromColor.b - toColor.b) * delta);

  return `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`;
};

const patches = document.getElementById('patches');

for (let i = 0; i <= 100; i += 5) {
  const color = interpolateBetweenColors(
    { r: 0, g: 255, b: 0 },
    { r: 255, g: 0, b: 0 },
    i
  );
  
  const patch = document.createElement('div');
  patch.style.backgroundColor = color;
  patch.style.width = '100px';
  patch.style.height = '10px';
  patches.appendChild(patch);
}
```

```html
<div id="patches"></div>
```

Comment: Best anwer so far. Thank you for providing an rgb alternative to using hsl colour values.

Answer (score 7):

```
function hexFromRGBPercent(r, g, b) {
    var hex = [
        Math.floor(r / 100 * 255).toString( 16 ),
        Math.floor(g / 100 * 255).toString( 16 ),
        Math.floor(b / 100 * 255).toString( 16 )
    ];
    $.each( hex, function( nr, val ) {
        if ( val.length === 1 ) {
            hex[ nr ] = "0" + val;
        }
    });
    return hex.join( "" ).toUpperCase();
}
```

Credit goes to andrew.  He was faster.

Answer (score 5):

Changing from `red` to `green` color using HLS. The value should be from 0 to 100, in this case simulating percentage (%).

```
function getColorFromRedToGreenByPercentage(value) {
    const hue = Math.round(value);
    return ["hsl(", hue, ", 50%, 50%)"].join("");
}
```

Comment: Very nice because it supports decent muted colors if you need them :)

Answer (score 3):

Based on Jacobs answer I made a loadbar. 
This one is from green to red, but you can change the colors.
For those interested here's my code and the jsfiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/rxR3x/ )

```
var percentColors = [
    { pct: 0, color: '#00FF00' },   { pct: 3, color: '#12FF00' },   { pct: 6, color: '#24FF00' },
    { pct: 10, color: '#47FF00' },  { pct: 13, color: '#58FF00' },  { pct: 16, color: '#6AFF00' },
    { pct: 20, color: '#7CFF00' },  { pct: 23, color: '#8DFF00' },  { pct: 26, color: '#9FFF00' },
    { pct: 30, color: '#B0FF00' },  { pct: 33, color: '#C2FF00' },  { pct: 36, color: '#D4FF00' },
    { pct: 40, color: '#E5FF00' },  { pct: 43, color: '#F7FF00' },  { pct: 46, color: '#FFF600' },
    { pct: 50, color: '#FFE400' },  { pct: 53, color: '#FFD300' },  { pct: 56, color: '#FFC100' },
    { pct: 60, color: '#FFAF00' },  { pct: 63, color: '#FF9E00' },  { pct: 66, color: '#FF8C00' },
    { pct: 70, color: '#FF7B00' },  { pct: 73, color: '#FF6900' },  { pct: 76, color: '#FF5700' },
    { pct: 80, color: '#FF4600' },  { pct: 83, color: '#FF3400' },  { pct: 86, color: '#FF2300' },
    { pct: 90, color: '#FF1100' },  { pct: 93, color: '#FF0000' },  { pct: 96, color: '#FF0000' },
    { pct: 100, color: '#FF0000' }
];
var getColorPercent = function(selector, percent, time){
    var i = 0;
    var percentInterval = setInterval(function() {
         i++;
         if(percent >= percentColors[i].pct) {
            console.log(percentColors[i].color);
            $(selector).css('background-color', percentColors[i].color);
        }
        if(percentColors[i].pct>=percent) {
            clearInterval(percentInterval);
        }
    }, time/25);
    $(selector).animate({width:(200/100)*percent}, time);
}
getColorPercent('#loadbar_storage', 100, 1500);
```

```js
var percentColors = [
    { pct: 0, color: '#00FF00' }, { pct: 3, color: '#12FF00' }, { pct: 6, color: '#24FF00' },
    { pct: 10, color: '#47FF00' }, { pct: 13, color: '#58FF00' }, { pct: 16, color: '#6AFF00' },
    { pct: 20, color: '#7CFF00' }, { pct: 23, color: '#8DFF00' }, { pct: 26, color: '#9FFF00' },
    { pct: 30, color: '#B0FF00' }, { pct: 33, color: '#C2FF00' }, { pct: 36, color: '#D4FF00' },
    { pct: 40, color: '#E5FF00' }, { pct: 43, color: '#F7FF00' }, { pct: 46, color: '#FFF600' },
    { pct: 50, color: '#FFE400' }, { pct: 53, color: '#FFD300' }, { pct: 56, color: '#FFC100' },
    { pct: 60, color: '#FFAF00' }, { pct: 63, color: '#FF9E00' }, { pct: 66, color: '#FF8C00' },
    { pct: 70, color: '#FF7B00' }, { pct: 73, color: '#FF6900' }, { pct: 76, color: '#FF5700' },
    { pct: 80, color: '#FF4600' }, { pct: 83, color: '#FF3400' }, { pct: 86, color: '#FF2300' },
    { pct: 90, color: '#FF1100' }, { pct: 93, color: '#FF0000' }, { pct: 96, color: '#FF0000' },
    { pct: 100, color: '#FF0000' }
];
var getColorPercent = function(selector, percent, time) {
  var i = 0;
  var percentInterval = setInterval(function() {
    i++;
    if (percent >= percentColors[i].pct) {
      $(selector).css('background-color', percentColors[i].color);
    }
    if (percentColors[i].pct >= percent) {
      clearInterval(percentInterval);
    }
  }, time / 25);
  $(selector).animate({
    width: (200 / 100) * percent
  }, time);
}
getColorPercent('#loadbar', 100, 1500);
```

```css
#loadbar_wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #CECECE;
}

#loadbar {
  width: 0px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="loadbar_wrapper">
  <div id="loadbar"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what I came up with:

```
function rgbify(maxval, minval, val, moreisgood) {
    var intnsty = (val - minval) / (maxval - minval);
    var r, g;
    if (moreisgood) {
        if (intnsty > 0.5) {
            g = 255;
            r = Math.round(2 * (1 - intnsty) * 255);
        } else {
            r = 255;
            g = Math.round(2 * intnsty * 255);
        }

    } else { //lessisgood
        if (intnsty > 0.5) {
            r = 255;
            g = Math.round(2 * (1 - intnsty) * 255);
        } else {
            g = 255;
            r = Math.round(2 * intnsty * 255);
        }
    }
    return "rgb(" + r.toString() + ", " + g.toString() + ", 0)";
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/keithxm23/7jyzmm0g/1/)

The `moreisgood` flag toggles if higher values should be red or green.
`maxval` and `minval` are the threshold values for your range.
`val` is the value to be converted to rgb

Answer (score 2):

Modify these two lines in Jacob's code:

```
var lower = percentColors[i - 1];
var upper = percentColors[i];
```

to:

```
var lower = (i === 0) ?  percentColors[i] : percentColors[i - 1];
var upper = (i === 0) ? percentColors[i + 1] : percentColors[i];
```

if you want to make it work for the two extremes (i.e. 0.0 and 1.0).

Answer (score 2):

I know this is kind of bump to topic but I found one more way of doing it.

To do this you can also create a dynamic canvas of 100x1 dimension and apply gradient to it and then from function you just need to get pixel color of the percent location.

Here is the code : 
This is global:

```
/* dynamic canvas */

// this should be done once in a page so out of function, makes function faster
var colorBook = $('<canvas />')[0];
colorBook.width = 101;
colorBook.height = 1;
var ctx = colorBook.getContext("2d");
var grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 101, 0);
grd.addColorStop(0, "rgb(255,0,0)"); //red
grd.addColorStop(0.5, "rgb(255,255,0)"); //yellow
grd.addColorStop(1, "rgb(0,255,0)"); //green    
ctx.fillStyle = grd;
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 101, 1);
```

Then the function:

```
function getColor(value) {
  return 'rgba(' + ctx.getImageData(Math.round(value), 0, 1, 1).data.join() + ')';
}
```

**Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/asu09csj/**

Answer (score 1):

HSL will work in IE8 using jquery-ui-1.10.4.

I modified jongo45's answer to accept lightness in the function.

```
function getColor(value, lightness) {
    //value from 0 to 1
    var hue = ((value) * 120).toString(10);
    return ["hsl(", hue, ",100%,", lightness, "%)"].join("");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mattisdada's code was really helpful for me while I was making a chart to display statistics of some quiz results. I modified it a bit to allow "clipping" of the percentage (not sure what the right term is) and also to work both ways along the colour wheel, e.g. both from green(120) to red(0) and vice versa.

```
function pickColourByScale(percent, clip, saturation, start, end)
{
    var a = (percent <= clip) ? 0 : (((percent - clip) / (100 - clip))),
        b = Math.abs(end - start) * a,
        c = (end > start) ? (start + b) : (start - b);
    return 'hsl(' + c + ','+ saturation +'%,50%)';
}
```

Basically, by setting a percentage value to clip the scaling at, everything below that value will be coloured as your start colour. It also recalculates the scaling according to 100% - clip.

Let's go through an example scenario where I enter the following values:

- percent: 75
- clip: 50
- saturation: 100 (unimportant, I use this for highlighting a Chart.js chart)
- start: 0 (red)
- end: 120 (green)

  1. I check if percent is less than clip, and I return 0% if it is. Otherwise, I recalculate the percentage - 75% is halfway between 50% and 100%, so I get 50%. This gives me 0.5.
  2. I get the difference between start and end. You need to use Math.abs() in case your start hue value is more than your end hue value. Then I multiply the difference by the result obtained in step 1 to see how much I need to offset the start hue value.
  3. If the start value is more than the end value, then you need to move along the colour wheel in the opposite direction. Add to or subtract from the start value accordingly.

I end up with yellow, which is halfway between red and green. If I hadn't done the recalculation in step 1, I'd have ended up with a more greenish colour, which could be misleading.

Answer (score 1):

That's actually pretty simple with hsl

```
const color = `hsl(${score},100%,40%)`
```

Answer (score 0):

Using similar logic as Jacob's top answer,

I have created a Javascript `color-scales` that handles it for you. You are also able to input multiple color stops as well as set a transparency level.

A live demo is here: https://codepen.io/dalisc/pen/yLVXoeR

Link to the package is here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/color-scales

Example usage:

```js
const ColorScale = require("color-scales");
let colorScale = new ColorScale(0, 100, ["#ffffff", "#000000"], 0.5);
let rgbaStr = colorScale.getColor(50).toRGBAString(); // returns "rgba(127,127,127, 0.5)"
```

The package is able to output a hex, rgb, or rgba string depending on your needs. It can also output a custom Color object ({r,g,b,a}) in case you need to cherry-pick the individual color components.

I came across a similar issue when trying to mimick a Tableau dashboard on a Javascript-based application. I realised it is a common feature of data visualization tools such as Tableau and Microsoft Excel, so I have created an npm package to handle it on Javascript application. If you would like to reduce your code, you could use the package.