# Generate gradient step based on dynamic value, including decimals

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hsl

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128675/from-green-to-red-color-depend-on-percentage), which has a [fabulous answer for values from 0..1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17268489/736893), I tried to modify the function to include the min and max values.

```
function getColor(value, min, max){
    var hue=((max-(value-min))*120).toString(10);
    return ["hsl(",hue,",100%,50%)"].join("");
}
```

It seems to work fine for whole numbers, but not so much for decimals.  For instance, these work as expected:

```
var value=42;
var d=document.createElement('div');
d.textContent="value="+value + " (this should be green)";
d.style.backgroundColor=getColor(value,42,100);
document.body.appendChild(d);

var value=42;
var d=document.createElement('div');
d.textContent="value="+value + " (this should be red)";
d.style.backgroundColor=getColor(value,0,42);
document.body.appendChild(d);
```

But these do not:

```
var value=0.1;
var d=document.createElement('div');
d.textContent="value="+value + " (this should be green)";
d.style.backgroundColor=getColor(value,0,90);
document.body.appendChild(d);

var value=0.1;
var d=document.createElement('div');
d.textContent="value="+value + " (this should be green)";
d.style.backgroundColor=getColor(value,0,5);
document.body.appendChild(d);
```

The last one is actually blue...  [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sNKWK/392/).  How can I change this to work with all 4 scenarios?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work very well:

```
function getColor(value, min, max){
    if (value > max) value = max;
    var v = (value-min) / (max-min);
    var hue=((1 - v)*120).toString(10);
    return ["hsl(",hue,",100%,50%)"].join("");
}
```

edit: adjusted based on comments below

Comment: I think your code is incorrect, the function expects a normalized value between 1-0, so just make sure your input value gets normalized between 1-0 based on min/max. Then just feed the function that value.
http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/70807

Comment: Can you elaborate? `var v = (value-min) / max;` should always be a value between 1-0, no?  Why would I do more calculations outside the function?

Comment: According to the answer above about normalization. That formula is not correct. While its near correct, its not completely correct.
E.g. feeding in a value which is equal to max, will not give you 1.
For example: min = 4, max = 1000, value = 1000, v => 0.996
but should be 1

Comment: Okay, so what is the solution?

Comment: subtract min from max?

Comment: yep thats correct :D didn't realize yesterday its that simple.