# Get hexadecimal color based on humidity

Tags: javascript, typescript, colors

I'm trying to find a formal way to calculate the color hexadecimal based on a relative humidity value, expressed in percent.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2jw1.png) is an example of the color gamma I'd like to use, which is the most commonly used

Is there any method I can use?

Comment: what is humidity value in color context?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the relative humidity value, expressed in percentual @KamilKiełczewski

Comment: So you want 0% mapped to #000, and 100% mapped to #FFF? What are the intermediate values? Red? Green? Blue? Gray?

Comment: what is relative humidity value in color context?

Comment: I think I'd go with the "standard" scale, an example of which can be seen [here](https://www.ac-heatingconnect.com/wp-content/uploads/ACHC-Home-Humidity-Relative-Humidity.png) @CalvinGodfrey

Comment: Possible duplicate of [from green to red color depend on percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128675/from-green-to-red-color-depend-on-percentage)

Comment: Any update? Did my answer help you? If so, it's recommended that you mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the comment with the image, I'd say the best way to do it is as follows:

Find the RGB color components for the initial value (0% humidity) and final value (100% humidity). Then for each color component, you can do a linear map from start to finish. In pseudocode:

```
int startRed = 50; // I made up all these numbers!
int endRed = 100;
int startBlue = 75;
int endBlue = 125;
int startGreen = 100;
int endGreen = 255;
function percentToColor(double percent) { // percent is a double in [0.0, 1.0]
    int redValue = startRed + (endRed - startRed) * percent;
    int greenValue = startGreen + (endGreen - startGreen) * percent;
    int blueValue = startBlue + (endBlue - startBlue) * percent;
    return [redValue, greenValue, blueValue];
}
```

Again, this was pseudocode. You'll have to make it work for whatever language you want, and account for the types of different variables.

I'm also not 100% sure that this will yield the same gradient as in the image you linked, but in general it makes *a* gradient, even if it doesn't match perfectly.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I needed. It doesn't reproduce the same gradient as in the image, but it's ok.