# Calculate the color code for an array of numbers similar to excel

Tags: javascript

I have an array of numbers and want to calculate the color (like #559e43) for each of these figures:

```
var numbers = [322.5,256.0,209.0,309.0,493.0,261.0,313.0,228.0,376.0,322.0,327.5,332.0,272.0,387.0,451.0,247.0,329.0,314.0];
```

The goal is to have a function getColorCode() to retrieve the color for each number in the array.

```
var maxval = Math.max(...arr);
var minval = Math.min(...arr);

for(var i=0;i<numbers.length;i++){
   getColorCode(numbers[i], minval, maxval);
}​
```

The formatting rule should be the same/similar to what is shown in the screenshot (Excel)

[image: Formatting Rule]

Comment: And the problem/question is?

Comment: `getColorCode()` has to know all numbers (or at least min and max) and not only one as the resulting color is relative to lowest and highest value.

Comment: would it be ok to make the function`getColorCodes(numbers)` and return a list of `number` and `colorCode`? As the above comment notes - you need to know the range to do it like excel

Comment: Of course, we need to pass min, max values to getColorCode() too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 parts to this.

1. Calculating the distribution across the range
2. Interpolating a colour given a percentage across the range

Number 1 is easy if just using percent for demonstration:

```
var min = Math.min.apply(null,numbers);
var max = Math.max.apply(null,numbers);
var numPct = numbers.map(value => ({value,pct: ((value - min) / (max - min))}))
```

Nuber 2 is a little more involved, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7128796/219661) helped (with some minor variation).

Note that the below uses *percent* for simplicity and excel uses *percentile* - an exercise for the reader is distribute accordingly.

```js
var percentColors = [
    { pct: 0.0, color: { r: 0x00, g: 0xff, b: 0 }},
    { pct: 0.5, color: { r: 0xff, g: 0xff, b: 0 } },
    { pct: 1.0, color: { r: 0xff, g: 0x00, b: 0 } } ];

var getColorForPercentage = function(pct) {
    for (var i = 1; i < percentColors.length - 1; i++) {
        if (pct < percentColors[i].pct) {
            break;
        }
    }
    var lower = percentColors[i - 1];
    var upper = percentColors[i];
    var range = upper.pct - lower.pct;
    var rangePct = (pct - lower.pct) / range;
    var pctLower = 1 - rangePct;
    var pctUpper = rangePct;
    var color = {
        r: Math.floor(lower.color.r * pctLower + upper.color.r * pctUpper),
        g: Math.floor(lower.color.g * pctLower + upper.color.g * pctUpper),
        b: Math.floor(lower.color.b * pctLower + upper.color.b * pctUpper)
    };
    return 'rgb(' + [color.r, color.g, color.b].join(',') + ')';
    // or output as hex if preferred
}  

var numbers = [322.5,256.0,209.0,309.0,493.0,261.0,313.0,228.0,376.0,322.0,327.5,332.0,272.0,387.0,451.0,247.0,329.0,314.0];

var min = Math.min.apply(null,numbers);
var max = Math.max.apply(null,numbers);
var numPct = numbers.map(value => ({value,pct: ((value - min) / (max - min))}))

var out = document.querySelector("#output");


for(var i=0;i<numPct.length;i++){
   var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.style.backgroundColor = getColorForPercentage(numPct[i].pct)
  div.innerHTML = numPct[i].value;
  out.append(div);
}
```

```html
<div id="output">

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that! I think your output is the same as what I've come up with. (using a function from another post) https://jsfiddle.net/vu29dpwf/2/