# Tailwind: from green to red color depend on percentage using Tailwind css

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I need background color map from green to red based on a progress variable (like in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jongobar/sNKWK/)).

```
function getColor(value){
    //value from 0 to 1
    var hue=((1-value)*120).toString(10);
    return ["hsl(",hue,",100%,50%)"].join("");
}
var len=20;
for(var i=0; i<=len; i++){
    var value=i/len;
    var d=document.createElement('div');
    d.textContent="value="+value;
    d.style.backgroundColor=getColor(value);
    document.body.appendChild(d);
}
```

As already answered [here on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128675/from-green-to-red-color-depend-on-percentage) but using Tailwind CSS. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current solution, generates color value on the fly. To fake such effect with Tailwindcss, I think it is reasonable to make a set of 11 colors to use. They can be called `color-range-0, color-range-1,...color-range-10` and then in assign them directly by making this modification:

```js
//old:
d.style.backgroundColor=getColor(value);

//new:
d.classList.add("bg-color-range-" + i);
```

and this is what should go to tailwindcss config file:

```js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        "color-range": {
          0: "#00FF00",
          1: "#33ff00",
          2: "#66ff00",
          3: "#99ff00",
          4: "#ccff00",
          5: "#ffff00",
          6: "#ffcc00",
          7: "#ff9900",
          8: "#ff6600",
          9: "#ff3300",
          10: "#ff0000",
        }
      },
    },
  },
  variants: {},
  plugins: [],
}
```

Result would be something like this:

[image]

Just keep in mind if you are using postcss to remove unused styles, you need to keep the name of these styles somewhere in comments in your html file.