# Change SVG Circular Progress Bar stroke according to colour in linear gradient

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, svg, linear-gradients

I'm trying to make an SVG circular progress bar change color according to progress/percentage from a linear gradient using CSS and JavaScript (react too).

So far, every solution I find has hard coded color codes or using jQuery which I cannot use.
My code and CSS is following.

```
  <svg viewBox="0 0 36 36" className="circular-chart">
  <path className="svg-back"
    fill='none'
    stroke={props.theme.colors.Neutral.Gray1}
    strokeWidth={3}
    d="M18 2.0845
  a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
  a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831"
  />
  <path className="circle"
    stroke-dasharray={`${props.percentage} 100`}
    d="M18 2.0845
  a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
  a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831"
  />

  <text
    x={18}
    y={21}
    className="svg-circle-text">
    {props.percentage}%
  </text>
</svg>
```

CSS:

```
    .svg-circle-text {
      font-size: 0.5rem;
      text-anchor: middle;
      fill: ${theme.colors.Primary.Black}
      font-weight: bold;
  }

  .circular-chart {
    display: block;
    margin: 10px auto;
    max-width: 80%;
    max-height: 250px;
  }
  
  .circle {
    stroke: #99DA98;
    fill: none;
    stroke-width: 3;
    stroke-linecap: round;
    animation: progress 1s ease-out forwards;
  }
  
  @keyframes progress {
    0% {
      stroke-dasharray: 0 100;
    }
  }
```

In another component, I have the following background which serves as kind of a key to this circular progress bar:

```
 background: linear-gradient(
      90deg,
      #99da98 0%,
      #f8b66a 51.56%,
      #cf6767 100%
    );
```

So if the percentage is, say, 60%, it should show the value of the gradient at 60%. A little help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I can't see where the % is set.

Comment: @AHaworth its in the second path in the svg ` stroke-dasharray={`${props.percentage} 100`}`

Comment: have you tried using hsl?

Comment: @MatanSanbira that sounds like a possible solution. i did not know about it. will check it out

Comment: You can do some arithmetic on the r g b settings as they are linear, at least in those two intervals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So with the help of a comment left by A Haworth, I searched for rgb arithmetic solutions and found almost exactly what I required in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128675/from-green-to-red-color-depend-on-percentage/18085357#18085357) answer. hsl was also an option but rgb sounded simple enough. with some changes in the following code (from the other question) i was able to achieve what I wanted.

```
function getGreenToRed(percent){
            r = percent<50 ? 255 : Math.floor(255-(percent*2-100)*255/100);
            g = percent>50 ? 255 : Math.floor((percent*2)*255/100);
            return 'rgb('+r+','+g+',0)';
        }
```

Comment: ok wow this helped me. however, i returned using template literals like ``rgb(${r},${g},0)``