# Green through to red in scss

Tags: css, sass

I'm using SCSS for this project.

I'm needing to create 100 classes from green through to red based on a percentage value. So 100% will be green, 0% will be red.

I'm wanting it to fade through so at about 50% it will be orange etc.

I assume there's something you can do with SASS but I don't have the knowledge where to even start.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm assuming it would be some magic hocus pocus involving a for loop and RGB or hex values for green and red, but I don't know enough about how RGB/hex values represent colors to figure out the range of stuff to loop through and generate the 100 colors. This help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161369/html-color-codes-red-to-yellow-to-green

Comment: Cheers @MichaelCoker that did the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to Michael Coker for the solution. See below for the SCSS converted function.

```
$red: 255;
$green: 0;
$count: 0;
$step: 5.1;

@while $green < 255 {
  $green: $green + $step;
  @if ($green > 255) { $green: 255; }

  .percent-#{$count} {
    background-color: darken(rgb($red, $green, 0), 10%);
  }

  $count: $count + 1;
}

@while $red > 0 {
  $red: $red - $step;
  @if ($red < 0) { $red: 0; }

  .percent-#{$count} {
    background-color: darken(rgb($red, $green, 0), 10%);
  }

  $count: $count + 1;
}
```

I did darken it by 10% as it was a bit too intense.

Answer (score 4):

Sass has a native native mix function `mix($color-1, $color-2, $weight)`
the $weight being the amount of $color-1 you add in percentage.

Ref: http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html

The loop below will generate 101 classes .class-0 ... .class-100 switching from 0% red to 100% red.

```
@for $i from 0 through 100 {
    .color-#{$i}{ background: mix(red, green, $i);}
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I did have this at one stage but didn't like the orange it gave. Wasn't very pleasant in the application. The other function returns a much more pleasant gradient of colours. Credit to you though as that is what I was asking for.